# How do you setup local.conf for devstack?

Tags: networking, openstack, devstack

I am trying to set up devstack in a test environment.  I eventually want to get to multi-node to show scaling, but for now I'd be glad if I could get it going within a single VM.  From what I can see, the critical bit is getting the local.conf setup correctly, but the documentation for it seems to be confusing or lacking.  I do see this bit on the single-node page:

> **Run DevStack**
>
> Now to configure stack.sh. DevStack includes a sample in
>   devstack/samples/local.conf. Create local.conf as shown below to do
>   the following:
>
> - Set FLOATING_RANGE to a range not used on the local network, i.e.
>     192.168.1.224/27. This configures IP addresses ending in 225-254 to be used as floating IPs.
> - Set FIXED_RANGE and FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE to
>     configure the internal address space used by the instances.
> - Set FLAT_INTERFACE to the Ethernet interface that connects the host to
>     your local network. This is the interface that should be configured
>     with the static IP address mentioned above.

OK so first, how does "192.168.1.224/27" translate to "225-254"?  Is this a typo that should say "225-251"?

Is "FLOATING_RANGE" the range of the VM's that are spun up and "FIXED_RANGE" the range of the host machines?  I'm guess - this isn't clear at all.  Which ones show up from outside the systems?  How are these used?  What is FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE?

The bigger question is, how can I set up DevStack in an environment where I don't have access a large IP address range?  Are the FLOATING_RANGE numbers just IP's internally and they don't need to be able to be reached directly from the outside?  Can I just use some non-public IP's that don't fit without our network topology, or do they need to be an explicit hole in our network IP range (i.e. there exists a default gateway, etc.)?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?  And doing so without leaving comments seems cowardly.  How do you view this as a not relevant question?  I'd like to refine it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So digging into the code myself, I've found that the notation used is [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) network notation.  Thus the 27 refers to 27 "1" bits that form the netmask.

I'm still working on figuring out what the FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE corresponds to (is this number of physical machines?).  I'll edit if/when I figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

4th octet of 192.168.1.224/27 is 111[00000]<-from 27 to 32 therefore the fixed subnet range is from 11100001 to 11111110 (excludes [00000] and [11111])

FIXED_RANGE is the range of VMs and you don't have to set FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE. FLOATING_RANGE is for external (public) network.

[ external network (FLOATING_RANGE) ] - [ gateway ] - [ internal network (FIXED_RANGE) ] - [VMs]

Comment: How should I fill the `FLOATING_RANGE`? Can I just put it randomly or what? Do I need to do additional configuration on my linux/ubuntu related to the FLOATING_RANGE I chose? I'm still confused on how any network access (run on my compute-node host) can be correctly routed to the VM instance using the floating IP